# Are there any free or open-source persistent publish/subscribe (PPS) systems?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, message-queue, raspberry-pi, qnx

I've been working with QNX lately and found their Persistent Publish/Subscribe (PPS) to be very useful. Does anyone know if there are any systems that are similar to QNX PPS that might work with the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact requirements are, but [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Did it do what you searched for?